# Functional differential equation (from Quantum Field Theory).

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, quantum-field-theory, functional-calculus

I have a certain differential equation that includes [functional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative). I know the solution, but I'm having a hard time to show that the equation is indeed solved by the solution. The background for this question is [quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) (in particular, [scalar $\phi^4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_interaction)).

The equation, called the [Schwinger-Dyson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation#An_example:_.CF.864), reads
$$
\nabla^2 \delta_xF[f]-\frac{g}{3!}\delta_x^3 F[f]-f(x)F[f]=0\tag{1}
$$
where $\delta_x$ is a functional derivative:
$$
\delta_x\equiv\frac{\delta}{\delta f(x)}\tag{2}
$$
and $F[f]$ is a functional of $f(x)$, a scalar function of $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Also, $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian on a certain manifold.

The standard method to solve this equation is through a "functional Fourier transform", where we formally integrate over the space of functions (also known as [functional integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration)). The solution supposedly reads (cf. [1]):
$$
F[f]\propto \exp\left[\frac{g}{4!}\int\mathrm dx\ \delta_x^4\right]\exp\left[\frac{1}{2}\int\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\ f(y)G(y-z)f(z)\right]\tag{3}
$$
where $G$ is a Green function of $\nabla^2$,
$$
\nabla^2G(x)\equiv\delta(x)\tag{4}
$$

**Question**

I know how to use the Fourier transform to solve $(1)$, and the solution is indeed $(3)$. But then I tried to plug $(3)$ back into $(1)$ and show that the equation is solved *without using functional integration*, and I failed. The expansion of the differential operator $\exp\left[\frac{g}{4!}\int\mathrm dx\ \delta_x^4\right]$ in power series in $g$ leads to a somewhat complicated combinatoric problem that I don't seem to be able to solve.

My attempt was as follows: take $(1)$ and let us suppose that $F$ can be expanded in power series in $g$:
$$
F[f]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty g^kF^{(k)}[f]\tag{5}
$$

Plugging this into $(1)$ and insisting that the equation is solved order by order in $g$, we get the system of equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla^2 \delta_xF^{(0)}[f]-f(x)F^{(0)}[f]&=0\\
\nabla^2 \delta_xF^{(k)}[f]-\frac{1}{3!}\delta_x^3 F^{(k-1)}[f]-f(x)F^{(k)}[f]&=0
\end{aligned}\tag{6}
$$

Now, the solution for $F^{(0)}$ is straightforward:
$$
F^{(0)}[f]\propto \exp\left[\frac{1}{2}\int\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\ f(y)G(y-z)f(z)\right]\tag{7}
$$

If we trust the solution $(3)$, then the solution for $F^{(k)}$ *should* be
$$
\begin{aligned}
F^{(k)}[f]&\overset?= \left(\frac{1}{4!}\int\mathrm dx\ \delta_x^4\right)^kF^{(0)}[f]\\
&\overset?=\frac{1}{4!}\int\mathrm dx\ \delta_x^4 F^{(k-1)}[f]
\end{aligned}\tag{8}
$$
but here I fail: there is no way I can show (say, with induction) that this indeed satisfies $(6)$. Thus, here I am. Can anyone help me to show that $(8)$ satisfies $(6)$?

Thank you in advance.

---

[1]: http://www.scl.rs/papers/QFT2notes.pdf, equation (2.23). Here the author uses functional integrals to solve the (generalised) Schwinger-Dyson equation, equation (2.12). In this post we use the notation $F[f]$ instead of $Z[J]$, and also the mass $m$ is zero to keep the analysis simple. Also, I have dropped some factors of $i$ to clean up the notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in this case, the proof that equation $(8)$ solves equation $(6)$ is indeed by induction. However, note first that there is a factor $1/k!$ (from the Taylor expansion of the exponential) missing in the first line of equation $(8)$, and a factor $1/k$ in the second line.

The inductive step starts by multiplying the second line of equation $(6)$ by$$\left({1\over{k + 1}}\right)\left({1\over{4!}} \int dz\,\delta_x^4\right)$$from the left. The first term immediately takes the desired form. The second term almost takes the desired form, but with an extra prefactor $k/(k + 1)$. The third term gives two contributions, by virtue of the product rule of (functional) differentiation. One contribution has the desired form $f(x) F^{(k + 1)}[f]$, the other one has a form similar to the second term, but with a prefactor $1/(k + 1)$ instead of $k/(k + 1)$. The two prefactors combine to $1$, bringing also the second term to the desired form.